# Origin of /h/ in ἅζομαι (házomai), ἁγνός (hagnós), ἅγιος (hágios)

Tags: etymology, ancient-greek, phonology, proto-indo-european

According to Wiktionary:

- [ἅζομαι (házomai)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%85%CE%B6%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%B1%CE%B9) ← PH **haďďomai* ← PIE **h₁yáǵyeti*
- [ἁγνός (hagnós)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%81%CE%B3%CE%BD%CF%8C%CF%82) ← PH **hagnós* ← PIE **h₁yáǵnós*
- [ἅγιος (hágios)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%85%CE%B3%CE%B9%CE%BF%CF%82) ← PH **hágijos* ← PIE **h₁yáǵyos*

I am aware of Proto-Hellenic /h/ coming from earlier */s/ and sporadically from */w/.

I would expect initial [laryngeal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Greek_language#Laryngeal_changes) **h₁* to be vocalized into */e/, resulting in Proto-Hellenic **ejaďďomai*, **ejagnós*, **ejágijos*, and in post-Proto-Hellenic period, loss of intervocalic */j/ and possible contraction of vowels.

What is origin of initial /h/ in actually attested forms of these words? Was this any regular process?

Comment: I wonder if this *h₁y- > h pattern appears in anything _not_ from \*h₁yeh₂ǵ-. I certainly can't think of any other examples.

Comment: @Draconis ἧπαρ < *\*Hi̯ekʷr̥* and ἵημι < *\*(H)i̯eh₁-* come to mind. ὑσμίνη < *\*Hi̯udʰ-* possibly as well, if that reconstruction is right, though obviously words starting with υ always have rough breathing.

Answer (score 7):

It is well known that the PIE sound -y- (also written -i̯-) shows a 'double reflex' in initial position in Greek: either ζ or rough breathing. From what I remember, it has been conjectured that the later was regular after a laryngeal, but this has been disputed. I don't know that much about the current state of this hypothesis. Aside from the references on Wiktionary, you could look at the references cited in "Greek", by Lucien van Beek (in *The Indo-European Language Family: A Phylogenetic Perspective*, pp. 173 - 201
DOI: https://doi.org/10.1017/9781108758666.011, Cambridge University Press, 2022), which says

> The double reflex of *i̯-, which merges with **di̯-* (plus **gi̯-, *gʷi̯-*) in one subset of lexemes that have correspondences with **i̯-* in other IE languages (e.g. *ζέω* ‘boil’, Myc. *ze-so-me-no*; *ζυγόν* ‘yoke’ and *ζεύγνυμι* ‘connect’, Myc. *ze-u-ke-si*), but was retained and developed into *h-* in another subset (relative pron. *ὅς*, Myc. *jo-*, *o-* beside Ved. *yáḥ*; *ἧπαρ* ‘liver’ beside Lat. *iecur*). The distribution between both reflexes, which is the same in all Greek dialects (including Mycenaean), represents an exclusive common innovation of Proto-Greek. The exact conditioning factor, probably the presence or absence of an initial laryngeal (cf. García Ramón 1999), is still disputed (cf. van Beek 2019).

The cited works are

- > Ramón, García, José, Luis. 1999. Griechisch Ζητήρ· Ζεὺς ἐν Κύπρῳ, vedisch yātar- und die Vertretung von *i̯ im Griechischen. In Eichner, Heiner, Luschützky, Hans Christian & Sadovski, Velizar (eds.), Compositiones Indogermanicae: Gedenkschrift für Jochem Schindler (1944–1994), 77–96. Prague: Enigma.
- > van Beek, Lucien. 2019. A look into the Indo-European bedroom: Vedic yóni- and Greek εὐνή. Historische Sprachforschung 132: 4–34.

Comment: So in a sense, it is preservation of initial laryngeal? Or would it be heresy? :)

Comment: (I will accept this answer in several days if there is no other answer.)

Comment: +1 – though I think you copied in the wrong García Ramón reference – it’s [García Ramón (1999)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/indoeuropean-language-family/greek/D7ECB74210D90E01F00D41B9930BC70A#REFe-r-11025), not 2017.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Thanks, you're right!